# tf static transform publisher

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in tf static transform publisher, what is the different between 
static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id period_in_ms 
 and 
 static_transform_publisher x y z qx qy qz qw frame_id child_frame_id  period_in_ms 
and what are the values that i'm suppose to use in  args such as:

Thank u.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206774/tf-static-transform-publisher/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first syntax is using [Euler Angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles), and the second syntax is using [Quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). They are just two different methods of representing the angular orientation of one frame relative to another. Typically Euler angles are convenient and easier to imagine, but Quaternions are more robust for numerical integration (e.g., when transitioning through pointing straight up or straight down), which is important in some specific situations.

But if you're just specifying a static transformation from one frame to another, you'll probably be fine with Euler angles, and they are more comprehensible for the next person that comes along and tries to understand the launch file.

---

Originally posted by [Morgan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19785/morgan/) with karma: 521 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF
This tutorials about publish TF maybe help you.

---

Originally posted by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) with karma: 214 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1